# RBAC For kubernetes Dashboard

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, google-kubernetes-engine, azure-aks

I have a User "A". I have namespaces X,Y,Z. I have created a RBAC user role and role binding for user "A" who has access to Namespace "X".

I wanted to give the user "A" access to kubernetes dashboard (which is a role and role binding for Kube-System). But when I give the access for dashboard, user "A" is able to see all the namespaces.

But I want him to see only namespace X which he has access).

How could I go about this?

Comment: Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on serverfault.com ...

Answer (score 2):

What's the version of your Dashboard? As far as I know, from 1.7 on, Dashboard has used more secure setup, It means, that by default it has the minimal set of privileges, that are required to make Dashboard work.

Anyway, you can check the privileges of the sa that used by Dashboard, make sure it has the minimal privileges, like this:

```
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: kubernetes-dashboard-minimal
  namespace: kube-system
rules:
  # Allow Dashboard to create 'kubernetes-dashboard-key-holder' secret.
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["secrets"]
  verbs: ["create"]
  # Allow Dashboard to create 'kubernetes-dashboard-settings' config map.
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["configmaps"]
  verbs: ["create"]
  # Allow Dashboard to get, update and delete Dashboard exclusive secrets.
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["secrets"]
  resourceNames: ["kubernetes-dashboard-key-holder", "kubernetes-dashboard-certs"]
  verbs: ["get", "update", "delete"]
  # Allow Dashboard to get and update 'kubernetes-dashboard-settings' config map.
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["configmaps"]
  resourceNames: ["kubernetes-dashboard-settings"]
  verbs: ["get", "update"]
  # Allow Dashboard to get metrics from heapster.
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["services"]
  resourceNames: ["heapster"]
  verbs: ["proxy"]
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["services/proxy"]
  resourceNames: ["heapster", "http:heapster:", "https:heapster:"]
  verbs: ["get"]

---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: kubernetes-dashboard-minimal
  namespace: kube-system
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: kubernetes-dashboard-minimal
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: kubernetes-dashboard
  namespace: kube-system
```

Then, create RBAC rules to give the full privileges for namespace X to A:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: user-A-admin
  namespace: X
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
subjects:
- apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: User
  name: A
```

Make sure user A doesn't have any other RBAC rules.

Comment: I have tried the above. User A has access to only namespace "X". But as the Kube-system has access to all the resources in the cluster Its showing all the namespaces to every user irrespective of the permissions

Comment: you should run Dashboard with  kubernetes-dashboard as the serviceaccount.

Comment: Do you know any article which clearly explains about this process? I mean service account etc

Comment: Take a look at https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#service-account-permissions and https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/wiki/Access-control